# What is the sum of the divisors of 14,601,359?

Tags: combinatorics

What is the sum of the divisors of 14,601,359?

$$14,601,359^2 -1 = 213,204,941,168,520$$

I'm not too sure if my calculation or logic is correct.

Comment: I don't understand what the question is.

Comment: @MJD: I have 14,601,359 how many piles can I make that are all of equal height? What would the sum of these piles be at the end once I had completed all combinations?

Comment: Now I don't understand what NumComparison is.

Comment: Sorry I'm not doing very well here.

Comment: @MJD apologies for this, please see the above, hopefully it's a bit clearer?

Comment: Are you looking for the sum of $14,601,359$'s divisors? Because that sounds like what you're attempting.

Comment: And are your piles allowed to have fractional pieces? E.g. if you split $14,601,359$ into two piles, each pile would have $7,300,679.5$ pieces. Is that allowed, or must your piles only consist of whole pieces?

Comment: @ScottCaldwell that's right! Thanks, couldn't have summed it up better myself (no pun intended).
That's correct with the 2 piles = 7,300,679.5, however it needs to be rounded down.

Comment: @ScottCaldwell - sorry I don't mean rounded down, whole numbers.

Comment: If you are interested in the sum of whole number divisors of 14,601,359, then you got off to a poor start illustrating this by "equal" piles numbering 2,3,5 (since none of those would divide the given number without remainder).  But the sum of its divisors is a mathematical question that is not without some interest and history.

Comment: @hardmath: I did indeed, right at the bottom of the learning curve. In fact, on another curve, on another graph. 
It would seem so.
In answer to the questions above;
$$14,601,359$$ is a prime number. I have taken away 1 to get the result;
$$Sum of Divisors: 21948120.   8 Divisors: 
1.2.491.982.14869.29738.7300679.14601358$$
[Divisors Calculator](http://www.javascripter.net/math/calculators/divisorscalculator.htm)
Thank you for every one input.

Comment: @WillJ: Right, for a prime number like $14601359$, the only possible piles are one pile with all the items, or so many piles with just one item each.  Thus the sum of divisors of a prime $p$ is $p+1$.  Knowing the prime factors of a number, $$14601358 = 2*491*14869$$ allows one to easily compute the sum of divisors $\sigma(14601358) = \sigma(2)*\sigma(491)*\sigma(14869)$.  There are roughly 400 Questions at Math.SE [about sum of divisors](http://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=sum-of-divisors+is%3Aquestion).

Comment: @hardmath - thank you for you help and pointing me in the right direction.